# JSON Stringify split every result

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to include BigQuery's query on my application, but I need to split my 
`html(JSON.stringify(response.result.rows, null))` 
to create a row every row.
Is there a way to do it without cycles?

Right now my results are `{Result1},{Result2},{Result3}`...

I expect something like:

```
{Result1}
{Result2}
{Result3}
```

Comment: What is the original value of `response.result.rows` before you stringify it?

Comment: [The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live?cb=1)

Comment: @AlexJolig the Question Wizard doesn't match perfectly with with my question...I tried follow it as much as I could

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it comes from the DB query, it is something like `{"f":[{"v":"Ciao Enrico!"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Come posso aiutarti?"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Ciao Cesare! Buon anno!"}]}`

Comment: You can ask in meta about how to fit my question in your wizard system. Help the community to fix the wizard problems

Answer (score 0):

```
"{Result1},{Result2},{Result3}".replace(/},{/g,"}\n{")
```

The best practice

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: "{Result1},{Result2},{Result3}".Replace is not a function

Comment: Try with `.replace`

Comment: just use lower case)

Comment: I still have some problems, 'cause the string contains other elements and its like: `[{"f":[{"v":"Ciao Enrico!"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Come posso aiutarti?"}]}, ... ]`

Comment: @evilGenius edit your answer then. Note that Javascript replace replaces the first occurrence in the way you call it. If you want a replace all, then you will need to use regular expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: but it's still have to work for you. cuz  we check by },{ , not just ,

Comment: @evilGenius no offence, but no. You should try your own solution before posting. "{Result1},{Result2},{Result3}".replace("},{","}\n{") replaces only the first occurrence of },{ to }\n{

Answer (score 0):

Simple: split your string by `},{` and join by `}\n{`:

```
html(JSON.stringify(response.result.rows, null).split("},{").join("}\n{"))
```